# node js for Arm cortex a5

Tags: node.js, npm, cross-compiling, cortex-a

```
I have an issue with cross compiling node.js to Cortex A5 target please guide me
```

I have an Atmel SAMA5D31-ek , running linux on it. Below is the CPU information

```
>cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp vfpv3 vfpv3d16 tls vfpv4 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc05
CPU revision    : 1

Hardware    : Atmel SAMA5
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

I am trying to cross compile node.js for my target board.(https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

> Corss compilation status : **successful**
>
> **node -v** : prints version of node i am using
>   but node with any other inputs gives **"Illegal instruction"**
>   checked with "file node" command, below is the result I got.
>
> **npm -v** results in **Illegal instruction**

```
# file node 
node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=ad3f999d0ef50a7a65ebee818c8b6b3c649e0640, not stripped
```

My target device does not have **ld-linux-armhf.so.3** , because my root file system is not using hard float.

> **Confusion :** what flags needs to set during cross compilation to work on my A5 target.

Below are the CC settings :

```
export CROSS_COMPILE="/home/abc/workspace/Linux/gcc-sourcery-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-"

export PATH=/home/abc/workspace/Linux/gcc-sourcery-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.03/bin:$PATH

export TOOL_PREFIX="arm-none-linux-gnueabi"

export CC="/home/abc/workspace/Linux/gcc-sourcery-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc"

export CXX="/home/abc/workspace/Linux/gcc-sourcery-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++"

export AR="/home/abc/workspace/Linux/gcc-sourcery-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar"

export RANLIB="/home/abc/workspace/Linux/gcc-sourcery-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib"

export LINK="${CXX}"

export CCFLAGS="-g -O3 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv4-d16 -march=armv7 -mtune=cortex-a5"

export CXXFLAGS="-g -O3 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv4-d16 -march=armv7 -mtune=cortex-a5"

./configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux 

make -j 4

**I am not clear about CCFLAGS and CXXFLAGS , please let me know where i went wrong and how to find the relevant information on these flags for particular processor platform.**
```